# Change the current slide with react-slick

Tags: reactjs, slick.js, react-slick

I'm using the react-slick library to make a slider, and I would like to change active slides and the slide which is at the top of the slider. For example, if I click on a button in the current page, I want the current slide at the top of the slider to change.

Do you know if is it possible to do this properly with this library?

I found a solution on the react-slick github (https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/issues/738), which consists of creating a ref to the slideshow and setting the focus via `this.slider.innerSlider.list.focus()`. However, this does not work very well, because the element I want is not at the very top of the slider. For example, if I set the focus on the second to last slide, the first element of my list is not accessible any more via the arrows.

Answer (score 4):

If `this.slider` is a ref to your Slick component, you can force the slideshow to show a slide by calling the method `slickGoTo()` with the index of the desired slide. For example, to show the second slide:

```
this.slider.current.slickGoTo(1);
```

For details on the methods that you can call using your ref, see: [react-slick API: Methods](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/api/#methods).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `SlickGoto()` method in slider `ref` and I will give you one of my solutions for this.

if your slider is a reusable component for example:

```js
import Slider from 'react-slick'
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.css'
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css'

function CustomSlider({ children, indexToGo }) {
  const settings = {
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 400,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
  }

  return (
    <Slider
      {...settings}
      ref={slider => {
        slider?.slickGoTo(indexToGo)
      }}>
      {children}
    </Slider>
  )
}

export default CustomSlider
```

here you need to pass the `indexToGo` which is the index of the slide you need to go and using slider `ref` with `slickGoTo()` method passing to it the `indexToGo`, now you easily can go to any slider using only the index of the slide you need to go.